# Django foreign key from different app is NoneType

Tags: python, django, django-models, celery

I have a model like this in a django 1.11.4 app which references a foreign key in different installed app (`django_celery_results`, listed in `settings.INSTALLED_APPS`):

```
class Worker(models.Model):
    tasks = models.ForeignKey('django_celery_results.TaskResult', null = True)
```

I can run `makemigrations happy_farm` and `migrate` without error, but when I try to access worker.tasks it is NoneType rather than the TaskResult manager:

```
$ from happy_farm.models import Worker
$ type(Worker.objects.first().tasks)
NoneType
```

Typically I'd expect to see something like `django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.ManyRelatedManager`.

I've also tried importing django_celery_results.models and referencing it directly, like:

```
import django_celery_results

class Worker(models.Model):
    tasks = models.ForeignKey(django_celery_results.models.TaskResult, null = True)
```

With the same outcome.

Comment: Does that instance have that field set? It maybe that the field is working, but the instance you're looking up has it as null.

Comment: The manager exists whether or not there are any records, so if it were working it would never be None.

Comment: The related field returned is an instance, not a QuerySet. The manager is not the returned object there. Try setting a task on a worker and querying that worker for its task.

Answer (score 0):

Since my objective is to have many tasks associated with one worker, the answer is that ForeignKey relationships need to be set on the Many side of a One-to-Many relationship (i.e. on the TaskResult model rather than on the Worker).

Comment: This is not an answer to the question as posted.